# Combining different terms in third column into one row according to sample code

Tags: csv, data, head

I have some genomic data with three columns. Column 1 is samples, Column 2 is cancer type, and Column 3 is mechanism. Each sample has one or more gene mechanisms assigned to it (e.g. 6 ecDNA) in the third row. Currently for each sample there are multiple rows per mechanism (So for e.g. sample x has 4 rows with the "6 ecDNA" mechanism  5 rows with the "5 deletion" mechanism where each row corresponds to one genetic aberration found for that sample).

I was wondering if there was a way to display all types of mechanisms in the data for each sample in one row

(e.g.   Sample  Cancer Abbrev  Mechanism)

```
     x        Bladder     6 ecDNA, 5 deletion
```

Is there a way to condense the types of mechanisms for a sample into one row?
Edit: This is a representative table of the OG dataset with example samples "x" and "y".

Sample,  Cancer Abbrev,   Mechanism

```
 x,       Bladder,         6 ecDNA

 x,       Bladder,         6 ecDNA

 x,       Bladder,         5 deletion

 x,       Bladder,         5 deletion

 y,       Osteosarcoma,    4 transposition

 y,       Osteosarcoma,    4 transposition

y,       Osteosarcoma,    5 deletion

y,       Osteosarcoma,    6 ecDNA
```

....

Comment: describing the data format is good, but showing a representative sample input is essential.  both together are even better.

Comment: Your question hints that the same data pairs may appear multiple times. Should they be counted?

Comment: @cas Alright, I have posted a representative sample of the data.

Comment: @FelixJN Not really, the number of times a certain mechanism appears in the rows for a single sample isn't as important as the number of types of mechanisms found in that sample.

Comment: are the columns separated by tabs or by spaces in your file?   I would guess tabs (at least, it should be tabs).   And are the blank lines between each record really there in your file or just because you couldn't format it correctly here on the web site?

Comment: @cat The columns are comma separated.

Comment: then you should have shown that.   "A representative sample of the input" means **exactly** that!  how are we supposed to figure out how to parse and process your data if you give us misleading information about it?

Comment: You should anonymise the data if it contains sensitive personal information, but otherwise the data sample you provide needs to be exactly what your data actually is.  Otherwise any answers you are given **won't work** when you try to run them on your real data.

Comment: You should also mention what format you want the output - i.e. do you want CSV output?  or tab-separated? or something else.

Comment: @cas I'd like to be tab-separated, but I can do it in a separate line of code.

Comment: @cas Sorry about that, I should be more careful when formatting representative data sets in the future when asking questions.

Comment: have you tried this way? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/655921/195582

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my %rec;

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  s/^\s+|\s*$//;
  next if m/^$/;

  my ($c1,$c2,$c3) = split /\s{2,}|\t+/;

  $rec{$c1}->{$c2}->{$c3} = 1;
}

# find the largest widths (lengths) of the first two columns, minimum 6 for each
my $l1=6;
my $l2=6;
foreach my $k1 (keys %rec) {
  $l1 = length($k1) if (length($k1) > $l1);
  foreach my $k2 (keys %{ $rec{$k1} }) {
    $l2 = length($k2) if (length($k2) > $l2);
  }
};

# use that to build a format string
my $fmt = "%-${l1}s\t%-${l2}s\t%s\n";

printf $fmt, "Sample", "Cancer", "Mechanisms";

foreach my $k1 (sort keys %rec) {
  foreach my $k2 (sort keys %{ $rec{$k1} }) {
    printf $fmt, $k1, $k2, join(", ",sort keys %{ $rec{$k1}->{$k2} });
  };
}
```

This perl script reads in each input line, removing any leading or trailing whitespace, and skipping empty lines.   I'm not sure if the input file has just one or more tabs separating each column, or multiple whitespace characters - I've written it to cope with either.

It builds a data structure called %rec to hold each record. The data structure is a multi-level hash (associative array), where the first two levels are the names of the first two columns (Sample and Cancer), and the third level contains the Mechanisms.

i.e. the %rec data structure ends up looking like this:

```
%rec = {
  x => { Bladder => { "5 deletion" => 1, "6 ecDNA" => 1 } },
  y => { Osteosarcoma => { "4 transposition" => 1, "5 deletion" => 1, "6 ecDNA" => 1 }, },
}
```

See `man perldsc` or `perldoc perldsc` for more info on perl data structures.  See also `man perlreftut` for a short tutorial on making and using such data structures.0

Once it has finished reading the entire input file, prints a summary line for each record (after figuring out how wide each column should be).  The output is tab separated.

Save it as, e.g. `combine.pl`, and make it executable with `chmod +x`.

```
$ chmod +x ./combine.pl
$ ./combine.pl input.txt
Sample  Cancer          Mechanisms
x       Bladder         5 deletion, 6 ecDNA
y       Osteosarcoma    4 transposition, 5 deletion, 6 ecDNA
```

Comment: change the `my ($c1,$c2,$c3) = split /\s{2,}|\t+/;` to `my ($c1,$c2,$c3) = split /\s*,\s*/;` to work with comma separated data.

Answer (score 1):

`datamash` is a simple tool for this. However one needs to remove empty lines and pay a bit more attention to the data input formatting.

```
sed '/^$/d' infile | datamash -W -g 1,2 unique 3,4
```

Means group based on columns 1 & 2, then collapse colums 3 & 4 to comma separated lists, but show unique values only. `-W` means use whitespace(s) (instead of tabs) as field delimiters. `sed` just deletes empty lines.
With your input file that would create such output:

```
Sample  Cancer  Abbrev  Mechanism
x   Bladder 5,6 deletion,ecDNA
y   Osteosarcoma    4,5,6   deletion,ecDNA,transposition
```

Note how Abbrev & Mechanism are grouped separately and be aware  that they are sorted independently from each other (i.e. `4` and `deletion` are first, where your in put has `4` as `transposition`) - this comes from the `unique` operation that needs sorting. For the exact output you requested, this would work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} $0 != "" {print $1,$2,$3" "$4}' infile |
datamash -g 1,2 unique 3

Sample  Cancer  Abbrev Mechanism
x   Bladder 5 deletion,6 ecDNA
y   Osteosarcoma    4 transposition,5 deletion,6 ecDNA
```

Here `awk` is used to make fields tab separated, but combine fields 3&4 into one by merely keeping a space between them - that way `datamash` treats them as one, as it by default works via tab as delimiter. `awk` also sieves out empty lines here.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), if your input is a CSV, you can run

```
mlr --c2t -N nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs "," -f 3 then clean-whitespace input.csv
```

to have

```
x Bladder      6 ecDNA,6 ecDNA,5 deletion,5 deletion
y Osteosarcoma 4 transposition,4 transposition,5 deletion,6 ecDNA
```

The input file I have used

```
x,Bladder,6 ecDNA
x,Bladder,6 ecDNA
x,Bladder,5 deletion
x,Bladder,5 deletion
y,Osteosarcoma,4 transposition
y,Osteosarcoma,4 transposition
y,Osteosarcoma,5 deletion
y,Osteosarcoma,6 ecDNA
```

If you want unique values the command is

```
mlr --c2p -N uniq -a then  nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs "," -f 3 then clea
n-whitespace input.csv
```

Comment: You are using `--explode` and make the single line into multiple records. OP's request is the reverse operation.

Comment: thank you @FelixJN I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

Assuming third and fourth fields have fixed values, i.e., `6` in third field always have `ecDNA` in fourth field, this should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"; printf "Sample\tCancer\tMechanisms\n"}
NF{len=split(ar[$1 OFS $2], a, " ");   
for(i=1;i<=len;i++) if (a[i] == $4) $4="";
if ($4) ar[$1 OFS $2]=(ar[$1 OFS $2] ? ar[$1 OFS $2]  ", " : "") $3 " " $4}
END{for(j in ar) print j,ar[j]}' input
```

In above command, `FS=","` because columns are comma separated and `OFS="\t"` because we want tab separated columns.